# Depending on (Id). How to place this database (Ppt) in (MP04 / MP 05)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Description: I have a sheet (Ppto) with a list of IDs (Id), Credits(Cedent) and Debits(Recept). I would like to move these transactions to MP05, If Id are equal. If Ids are not equal move to MP04. Criterion: If Id = use MP05. If Id ≠ use MP04.
I'm a novice in google script, I need some support.

[image]

Thanks for your attention

```
function mp() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ppto = ss.getSheetByName('Ppto.');
 var Id = ppto.getRange('B5:B12').getValues();
 var cedent = ppto.getRange('D5:D12').getValues();
 var recept = ppto.getRange('E5:E12').getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < cedent.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < recept.length; j++) {

        if (cedent[i]  != '' )   {
        if (recept[j]  != '' )   {
        //if (Id === Id) // MP-05
        //if (Id != Id) // MP-04  
        {
          ppto.getRange('H5:H12').setValues(cedent);
          ppto.getRange('I5:I12').setValues(recept);


          Logger.log(cedent[i]);

         ppto.getRange('j5:j12').setValues(cedent);
         ppto.getRange('k5:k12').setValues(recept);

    }
   } 
}
}
}
  }
```

Comment: Why not just use sheet formulas for this; why the need to script at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Strategy:

- FIFO: First-In First Out
- Loop through all rows using `forEach`
- If credit is present, Loop again through all rows using `some` to look for receipts
- If credit `e[2]` in first loop equals receipts `f[3]` in second loop, Check for id `[0]`
- If ID is equal, splice two empty columns at the end, else at the 2nd position to create a uniform 6-column array
- Set that array back to the sheet.

#### Sample Script:

```
function transactionSegregator() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ppto = ss.getSheetByName('Ppto.');
  var data = ppto.getRange('B5:E12').getValues();
  data.forEach(function(e) {
    //e: Each row
    if (e[2] && e.length == 4) {
      //e[2]:credits; If this row is not spliced
      data.some(function(f) {
        //f:Each row; Second loop
        if (e[2] == f[3]) {
          //if credits = debit
          if (e[0] == f[0]) {
            //if id = id, splice two empty columns after Col4, else after Col2
            e.splice(4, 0, '', '');
            f.splice(4, 0, '', '');
          } else {
            e.splice(2, 0, '', '');
            f.splice(2, 0, '', '');
          }
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  Logger.log(data);
  ppto.getRange(5, 6, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);// F5
}
```

#### References:

- [Javascript tutorial](https://w3schools.com/js)
- [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Thank you Dear @TheMaster, and how it would be if (MP-05 / MP-04) were two different sheets.
Excuse the English.

Comment: @Luis Instead of `splice`, You'll use `getRange(i,).copyTo()`. But, I'm NOT going to do it for you. Muse the  sample script above, read the references above, do all the exercises in the tutorial link, read the sheets documentation and try for a few days. You'll fail at first, but you'll succeed, if you don't give up.. But you have to put more effort. Try  and try. Cheers.

Comment: In which one would have to place the Id, assignor and recept in each of them

Comment: Very good thanks again for the support @TheMaster.
Health for yours and for you.